# JQuery select clicked div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have 4 divs , i want to get the clicked div and change it's style , my divs are dynamically created that is why I don't want to use the id

```
<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 1</div>
<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 2</div>
<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 3</div>
<div class="item">Lorem ipsum 4</div>
```

jquery code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.item').on("click", function() {
    // change style
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", ".item", function() {
  var elt = $(this);
  // do whatever you want with elt.css()
});
```

This way, you will catch every *click event* on any `.item` element, whenever the element is created (added to the page via ajax for instance)

More info about it on [jQuery Event Deleguation doc](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 5):

You need to use **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**.

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$('body').on("click",'.item', function() {
  // change style
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We first include jquery library.Then we style using css on jquery click event.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".item").click(function(){
     $(".item").css("color", "red");
     //we can style anything .css('property','value');
      });
    });

    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
```